# How to extract hostname from OCS ID

Tags: bash

I'm fixing a bash script on GLPI that displays machines that have not been updated for more than a month. Data in are displayed like this :

```
myhostname01t-2015-03-09-16-47-42
```

I'd like, through regex, get only the name : `myhostname01t`

I've created this regex :

`(.*)-([0-9]{4}.*)`

With sed how could i get only the name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple cut isn't enough? Easier to comprehend than sed.

```
echo 'myhostname01t-2015-03-09-16-47-42' | cut -d'-' -f1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for sed:

```
$ S="myhostname01t-2015-03-09-16-47-42"

$ sed 's/\(^[^-]\+\).*/\1/' <<<$S
myhostname01t
```

or even simpler with awk:

```
$ awk -F- '{print $1}' <<<$S
myhostname01t
```

Perl:

```
$ perl -F- -lane 'print $F[0]' <<<$S
myhostname01t
```

Answer (score 0):

If the aim is to extract the hostname from an OCS ID stored in one variable and put it in another variable then it can be done with pure Bash code:

```
ocsid='parta-1234-partb-2015-03-09-16-47-42'

hostname=${ocsid%-*-*-*-*-*-*}

printf 'hostname=%s\n' "$hostname"
```

See [Removing part of a string (BashFAQ/100 (How do I do string manipulation in bash?))](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for an explanation of `${ocsid%-*-*-*-*-*-*}`.